# Magento catalogrule: how to have prices ready and showing at midnight exactly?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

Magento catalogrule: how to have prices ready and showing at midnight exactly?

I've two catalogrules in my Magento ver. 1.9.2.1 shop:

1. Already started, has and end_date of today (so: it is effective until tonight at 23:59)
2. Starts tomorrow (so: tonight at midnight (00:00))

## tl;dr

How can I make `catalogrule_apply_all` calculate the prices both for now (with today rule) and for tomorrow (with tomorrow rule)?

## Longer version

My rules:

```
rule_id name    description from_date   to_date is_active   conditions_serialized   actions_serialized  stop_rules_processing   sort_order  simple_action   discount_amount sub_is_enable   sub_simple_action   sub_discount_amount
15  FIRST   NULL    2017-10-31  2017-11-02  1   snip, conditions are OK snip, actions are OK    1   0   by_percent  90.0000 1   by_percent  90.0000
16  SECOND  NULL    2017-11-03  NULL    1   snip, conditions are OK snip, actions are OK    1   0   by_percent  5.0000  1   by_percent  5.0000
```

Due to both marketing and local legislation, I need the timings to work as described (a few minutes off is ok, but 10 mins are already too much).

The problem is that if I run `catalogrule_apply_all` tomorrow at midnight, it takes 2 hrs to complete (the store has a 200.000 products and 50 rules), so we are waaay late.

So my strategy would be to run `catalogrule_apply_all` at 21:00 of today (the day before the 2nd rule is set to kick in), expecting to have the price pre-calculated and ready for midnight. That's not the case: **if I hack the clock to "tomorrow", I still see "today" prices**.

Database-wise, this is what I see (in a nutshell: records are OK as long as I run `catalogrule_apply_all` the same day of the rule).

If I run `catalogrule_apply_all` today at 21:00 (`sudo timedatectl set-ntp false && sudo date --set="2 nov 2017 21:00:00" && n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:run catalogrule_apply_all && n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:run catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all && n98-magerun.phar cache:dir:flush`), this is what I find in `catalogrule_product_price`:

```
rule_product_price_id   rule_date   customer_group_id   product_id  rule_price  website_id  latest_start_date   earliest_end_date
8   2017-11-01  0   120 2.9900  1   2017-10-31  2017-11-02
9   2017-11-02  0   120 2.9900  1   2017-10-31  2017-11-02
```

If I run `catalogrule_apply_all` tomorrow at 10:00am (I'm using a +10hrs offset from midnight to exclude any timezone interference, `sudo timedatectl set-ntp false && sudo date --set="3 nov 2017 10:00:00" && n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:run catalogrule_apply_all && n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:run catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all && n98-magerun.phar cache:dir:flush`), this is what I find in `catalogrule_product_price`:

```
rule_product_price_id   rule_date   customer_group_id   product_id  rule_price  website_id  latest_start_date   earliest_end_date
11  2017-11-03  0   120 28.4050 1   2017-11-03  NULL
12  2017-11-04  0   120 28.4050 1   2017-11-03  NULL
```

So... yes, **each rule iworks if I run `catalogrule_apply_all` the same day of the rule effective date**.

## Context

- flat tables are disabled
- I'm simulating with only one product in the dev DB. It's the one that's affected by the rule